# Magento 1.9.3 Pagination not working

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

Magento **pagination** on *product list* page is not working. When choosing different number of products to show from dropdown list,the *pager* (screenshot 1,2,3 ...) displying correct, but instead of showing the correct number of products on the page, it just display all products at once on the page.

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any module to override the Block getCollection method? it will interrupt the pager block for pagination

Comment: Do you mean this method?  $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();